# Satisfiable formula only over even structares

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

In First order Logics, what formula can I cook up, that's satisfiable over all even structures, and only even structures. (even structure means it has an even number of elements in its domain).

Comment: Hint: If your domain has an even cardinal, you can cut it in two parts (meaning that each element is in one of the parts and no element is in both parts) of equal size (meaning that you have a bijection between the two parts.

Comment: You can't, unless you consider every infinite cardinality to be "even". (And even so, the best you can achieve is "has a model of every even cardinailty" -- for every structure of even cardinailty to be a model is much more than you can do with a single formula of first-order logic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let our language have a binary relation symbol $R$. Let $\varphi$  be the sentence which is the conjunction of the following sentences:

(i) the sentence $\forall x\lnot R(x,x)$ that says $R$ is antireflexive;

(ii) the sentence $\forall x\forall y(R(x,y)\to R(y,x))$ that says $R$ is symmetric;

(ii) the sentence $\forall x\exists y(R(x,y)\land \forall t(R(x,t)\to t=y))$.

Then the  finite models of $\varphi$ are necessarily of even cardinality. And given any non-empty set $A$ of even cardinality, there is a model of $\varphi$ with underlying set $A$.

If $A$ is an infinite set, then $\varphi$ is satisfiable in $A$.  So in that sense all infinite cardinals are even. More precisely, the concepts "even" and "odd" are meaningless for infinite cardinals.

Comment: Is it ok to just use the sentence ∀x∃y(R(x,y)∧∀t(R(x,t)→t=y)) in order to express the desired property? why are the other two parts necessary?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. However, the sentence you suggest, by itself, is not enough. For example, let $A$ be a $1$-element set $\{a\}$, and suppose $R(a,a)$ holds. Then the sentence above is true, but the underlying set does not have even cardinality. There are many other models of odd cardinality.

Comment: ok, I get it - so  ∀x¬R(x,x) is important. But do I also need ∀x∀y(R(x,y)→R(y,x)) ? By the way - if the set A is empty - since it's also considered even, do these statements (i and iii (and ii if you say it's also necessary)) hold for an empty set?

Comment: The symmetry I put in just because it helps to visualize geometrically. One can live without it.  About $0$, the usual definition in logic of an $L$-structure includes that the underlying set is non-empty.  As long as we adhere to that convention, we cannot include $0$.

Comment: But suppose we would like to talk about empty structures - the said sentences are satisfied in a trivial way in those, right? The ∀ quantifier is ok when there are no elements at all.

Comment: Technically yes. But I cannot alter the "non-empty set $A$" part of my answer, since for accuracy the answer must use the standard meaning of $L$-structure.